# Sublime Text: "The system cannot find the file specified" error

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

First of all, I know that this question was asked many many many times however I found no answer to my problem by reading the other answers.

I'm playing a bit with Sublime Text 3 but can't understand the build systems at all!

I have the simplest Python file ever containing only `print 'test'`.

My build file is not much more complex, because it is:

```
{
    "selector": "source.python",
    "cmd": ["echo test"],
}
```

However, when trying to run it, I get:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['echo test']]
[dir: C:\P4\depot\test]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts]
[Finished]
```

From what I understood, this error occurs mainly because of `%PATH%` problems but I assume that it can't be the problem here as I call a system command.

So, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you using `echo test` as a build system for *Python* on *Windows*? Wouldn't you want to run your file using `python.exe`? Have you tried [researching](https://www.google.com/#q=sublime+text+build+systems) how to set up a build system (one already exists for Python, by the way)? Have you read the [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've read the docs but was just curious about build commands. It's why I created a dummy build system just to see how to execute commands. By the way, I found the answer to my question by replacing "cmd" by "shell_cmd"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those of you interested, the answer was simply to change:

```
"cmd": ["echo test"]
```

into

```
"shell_cmd": "echo test"
```

Once again, my question was not related to Python itself but more to build systems in Sublime Text that I've found very poorly documented.